# CSS Styling covering HTML hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I have a hover effect creating a label over an image that is also a hyperlink to a separate website, however, the hover effect CSS styling is blocking my HTML hyperlink to the other site.

I have the image aligned with multiple other images in a section of my current project, whenever I alter the div to create the link, it misaligns the  from the center.

Is there a quick fix that allows me to keep my image centered within CSS Grid and also allows the entire `<div class="big-image">`to be the hyperlink instead of just the image behind the label?

Here are the codeblocks for reference :

```css
   #projects{
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    /* Test color: #D7D427 */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.25fr 2fr 1.25fr;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 1fr 1fr 1fr ;

    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#work-title{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
.img1{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.img2{
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
.img3{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.img4{
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    max-width: 100%;
}



.big-image{
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}

/* Image Borders */
.img1 img, .img2 img, .img3 img,.img4 img, .big-image img{
     border: 3px solid var(--blue-border);
     border-radius: 25px;
}
/* Image/Project :hover effects for Labels */

.big-image {
    position: relative;
   
}
.big-label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 25px ;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
   /* pointer-events: none; */
}
.big-label > *{
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.big-label:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
.big-label:hover > *{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.big-label-title{
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.big-label-description{
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
 

<a href="https://mberti13.github.io/run-buddy/">
    <div class="big-image">
    <img id= "big-image" src="./assets/images/run-buddy-photo.jpg" width="500px" height="350px" alt="Website built for Run Buddy Inc. Made Using HTML and CSS">
    <div class="big-label">
        <div class="big-label-title">
    <h3>Run Buddy</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="big-label-description">
    <h5>HTML, CSS</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is **one** Problem:
`<h3><a href="https://mberti13.github.io/run-buddy/"></a>Run Buddy</h3>`

You have to put Text inner the anchor link. Like that:
`<h3><a href="https://mberti13.github.io/run-buddy/">Run Buddy</a></h3>`

Comment: I edited the code blocks to take out all anchor tags except at the top of the HTML parent element. Now the hyperlink works with the label, but it took the <div> out of the middle of the CSS Grid and up to the top right.

Comment: @mberti13 I didn't mean it that way. I only meant this one line in particular. 

What is right is that you need a triger for the hover effect. Then you have the extended block with the link.